# python error "Job information querying failed" on win10

Tags: python, pip, windows-10

I'm running python scripts that connect and read some information from some firmware (not so important for this question)

I'm using python 3.4.3, and scripts are working on win7,8, and even on win10 ver 10.0.10045.

But on newest win10 ver 10.0.10108 I get this above mentioned error.

```
Job information querying failed
```

I've googled it and found some opened issue here:
https://bugs.python.org/issue24127
It has something to do with PIP  (I'm new to python - I don't know what exactly pip is)
And I don't even know if this issue is what I'm seeing , or I get this same error for another reason.
I don't even know how to debug the problem.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The code and the traceback, please!

Answer (score 1):

https://bugs.python.org/issue24127 has been confirmed by a Windows dev to be a bug in current builds of Windows 10, and the issue has been closed.